# How add a ToolControl when the MPart was created dynamically?

Tags: eclipse, toolbar, e4

I have been created a MPart dinamically, a bunch of them when i click a tree element.

```
MPart part = MBasicFactory.INSTANCE.createPart();
part.setLabel(block.getName());
part.getTransientData().put("secondary_id", "ID."+block.getInstancePath());
part.setElementId("ID."+block.getName());
part.setTooltip(block.getInstancePath());
```

I nedd add a toolbar to that part that i created.

```
MToolBar toolbar = MMenuFactory.INSTANCE.createToolBar();
//create the tool item programmatically
MDirectToolItem element = MMenuFactory.INSTANCE.createDirectToolItem();
element.setElementId("myToolItemId");
element.setIconURI("platform:/plugin/test.rcp/icons/delete.gif");
element.setContributionURI("bundleclass://path_to_the_class");
toolbar.getChildren().add(element);
paart.setToolbar(toolbar);
```

The problem is that i need a bunch of items in the toolbar, and all the handled method interact with the Part, is possible add a ToolControl dynamically to the toolbar that's way i can group all the buttons of the toolbar in one single class.

Comment: MMenuFactory has a createToolControl method

Comment: Thanks @greg-449